# Format of Solaris Open Boot Prompt boot-device?

Tags: solaris, sparc

I have the following `boot-device`:

```
/pci@400/pci@1/pci@0/pci@4/scsi@0/disk@w32a6b2f6484021d2,0:a
```

And I would like to understand the syntax. What I know is:

- `/pci@400/pci@1/pci@0/pci@4/scsi@0`: This is the name of the controller shown by `probe-scsi-all`.
- `/disk`: It is obvious.
- `@w3`: I do not know.
- `2a6b2f6484021d2` is the WWID of the RAID volume as shown by `show-volumes` without the leading zero.
- `,0:a`: I guess this is the partition.

What is `@w3` and how to get it from the OBP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The disk id breakdown is actually slightly wrong:

- ...
- `/disk` is obvious
- `@` separates the device address (...`/disk` from the device identifier)
- `w` for this disk device type indicates the device identifier is a WWN
- `32a6b2f6484021d2` is the full WWN of the disk device
- `,0` is the LUN number.
- `:a` is the partition.

The full WWN is `32...` - however, if this is different than what `show-volumes` is showing you, then I assume this is one path of a multi-path connection to the disk (for example, a storage array with multiple fibre connections to the same SAN could present the same disk with different WWNs on each storage array SAN connection).  The `show-volumes` output shows the *volume* WWN, as opposed to the WWN of the path to get to that volume.

*Followup*:

From the Oracle documentation, it appears that this WWN value appears in the output from `probe-scsi-all`.  Their example is:

```
ok probe-scsi-all
/pci@400/pci@2/pci@0/pci@e/scsi@0

FCode Version 1.00.54, MPT Version 2.00, Firmware Version 5.00.17.00

Target a 
  Unit 0   Removable Read Only device   TEAC    DV-W28SS-R      1.0C                    
  SATA device  PhyNum 3 
Target b 
GB  Unit 0   Disk   SEAGATE  ST914603SSUN146G 0868    286739329 Blocks, 146 
  SASDeviceName 5000c50016f75e4f  SASAddress 5000c50016f75e4d  PhyNum 1 
Target 389 Volume 0 
  Unit 0   Disk   LSI      Logical Volume   3000    583983104 Blocks, 298 GB
  VolumeDeviceName 33b2999bca4dc677  VolumeWWID 03b2999bca4dc677

/pci@400/pci@1/pci@0/pci@b/pci@0/usb@0,2/hub@2/hub@3/storage@2
  Unit 0   Removable Read Only device    AMI     Virtual CDROM   1.00
```

Notice the `VolumeDeviceName 33b2999bca4dc677  VolumeWWID 03b2999bca4dc677` in `Target 389`.

- Target `389` is the same target number as in `show-volumes`
- `VolumeWWID` is the same WWID as in `show-volumes`
- `VolumeDeviceName` is the WWN that you need to use to reference the volume.

Comment: Which command outputs the `3...` WWN?

Comment: unfortunately, it's been long enough since I used SPARC that I don't remember exactly.  It *should* show up in the output of `probe-scsi-all`, or you can do something like `show-devs` to find all the devices, then for each `scsi` device, run the sequence `select /pci@400/pci@1/pci@0/pci@4/scsi@0` followed by `show-children` followed by `unselect-dev`

Comment: `show-volumes` shows WWNs. And those WWNs start with a 0 instead 3. I do not think, that the OBP knows anything about multi-path, which is an OS feature only visible to `format`. Nevertheless I have no multi-path, because it is just a RAID controller without multi-path. So the question is still open: where does the `3` come from?

Comment: what type of server?

Comment: T4-1 with LSI RAID controller (SAS2008)

Comment: `sas2ircu` reports the volume WWN as `02a6b2f6484021d2` but the `boot-device` contains `32a6b2f6484021d2`.

Comment: You need to use `probe-scsi-all` to find this information; I just updated the answer